# Access PDF file to pass to Adobe (Android)

Tags: android, pdf

New to Android, amazed by how difficult it is to work with PDFs.  I think I've put together code that will pass a PDF to an application like Adobe, and return an error if no such application is installed.

However, no file path given by `targetName` seems to work, whether I put `target` in assets or res/raw.  I don't care where the file is as long as the app can read it and pass it along.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what voodoo ritual I have to perform to open a PDF in Android?  I miss iOS PDFView.

```
public void openPdf(Context context, String targetName) {

File target = new File(targetName);

if (target.exists()) {
Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(target);
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

try{
context.startActivity(pdfIntent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You must have a PDF reader installed to view this document.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Die App ist kaput.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to use that intent you need to store all your pdf's on the SD card and then give the intent the uri to that pdf on the sd card.

example:

```
Uri pdfUri = Uri.parse(pdfUriString);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(pdfUri, "application/pdf");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

this will not work if you have your pdf's in your projects resources folder

Answer (score 0):

> However, no file path given by targetName seems to work, whether I put target in assets or res/raw.

Correct. This is equivalent to having a PDF file on a thumb drive, that is not plugged into a computer, then complaining that you are "amazed by how difficult it is to work with PDFs" in Windows.

> I don't care where the file is as long as the app can read it and pass it along.

Write it to [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). Or copy it to [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) and [use `FileProvider` to serve it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) via a `content://` `Uri` to third-party apps.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to complain or offend.  What is the purpose of `assets` or `res` if not to store things to be used when the app runs?

Comment: @ClaytonGeipel: Resources and assets are things for the app to use within its own process. That could be directly through its own code (plus the Android framework) or via libraries. However, once you get *third-party apps* involved, usually you are going to have to do something more. That's because while resources and assets are (awkwardly) readable by other apps, few developers bother to write apps to actually read them, focusing their efforts instead on more conventional data sources: files, URLs, and `ContentProviders`.

Comment: @ClaytonGeipel: Assets are even worse, in that there's no `Uri` syntax to point a third-party app at one of your assets. Might you find some PDF viewer that could directly read your raw resource? Perhaps. But I doubt that any of the popular ones do -- Adobe Reader, in particular, I'm sure does not. Hence, if you are going to rely on third party apps, it is incumbent upon you to make your data available in ways that such apps are likely to be able to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  If I write to external storage, the user must have an SD Card in place, right?  And I assume I'll have to write another method to erase this PDF once the user is done with it?

Comment: @ClaytonGeipel: "If I write to external storage, the user must have an SD Card in place, right?" -- the device must have external storage. Only few/old devices use a removable card for that. "And I assume I'll have to write another method to erase this PDF once the user is done with it?" -- yes, which unfortunately gets tricky, as you don't really know when the user is done with it. A typical pattern is to keep the file out there for X period of time and delete it afterwards, where you'd need to choose a value of X that suits your use case.